# UIAlertView with timestamp

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am a newbie to Objective-C. I would like to display the current date and time in an alert view.

```
- (IBAction)postButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender  {

    NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMM d, yyyy h:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];

    NSString *todayString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message Posted" message:@"Your Message is posted on: @todayString" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
      }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your alert message string needs to be redone.  Try this:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message Posted" 
message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Message is posted on: %@", todayString] 
delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concate `NSString` using `stringWithFormat:` or `stringWithString:` there's also other appeding functions available, [see doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message Posted" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Message is posted on: %@",todayString] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
[alert release]; //don't forget to release UIAlertView object if you don't using ARC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Message is posted on: %@", todayString];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message Posted" message:str delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
```